# AWS S3 event bridge rule to trigger lambda based on suffix

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-event-bridge

I have the below s3 path, every day a sub-folder(current_date=040423) will be created inside the data folder and a CSV will be put inside the created subfolder. How can I create an event bridge rule which should only trigger after a csv object has been put inside the sub-folder?

s3_path=s3://bucket_name/data/

I tried the following event pattern which didn't work. Could you please help with the event bridge rule to achieve this, any help would be highly appreciated.

```
{
  "detail-type": ["AWS API Call via CloudTrail"],
  "source": ["aws.s3"],
  "detail": {
    "eventSource": ["s3.amazonaws.com"],
    "requestParameters": {
      "bucketName": ["bucket_name"],
      "key": {
        "and": [{
          "prefix": "data/"
        }, {
          "suffix": ".csv"
        }]
      }
    },
    "eventName": ["PutObject"]
  }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need the suffix? Can't you just trigger it whenever _any_ object is created in that Prefix?

Comment: **Side-note:** As a data person, I recommend you name the files/folders in ISO format. So, instead of `040423`, name it `2023-04-04`. This sorts nicely and also makes it clear which field is the month vs the day.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein - If I just use a prefix in the event pattern, the lambda is getting triggered twice, one during the sub-folder creation and another invocation during the CSV object being put inside the created sub-folder

Comment: There is no need to create a folder in Amazon S3. You can simply create an object with a Key of `data/040423/foo.txt` and the `040423` folder will 'magically' appear. That will solve the double-trigger problem.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein - sub-folder creation is not manual, I have a script that creates the subfolder and downloads today's csv file from sftp server, and put it inside the sub-folder, then I want the event bridge to trigger another lambda based on put object for further processing.

Comment: You can remove the code that creates the subfolder. It is not necessary. Or, if you wish to keep doing this, the you can simply add some code in the Lambda function that checks whether the `Key` ends with `.csv`. If it does not, the Lambda function can exit immediately.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein - Thank you for your suggestions. I was asked to fix this by modifying the event bridge pattern, is there any way I can fix this by changing the event bridge pattern?

Comment: It is triggering on an API Call via CloudTrail? That's a strange way to respond to a new object being created in Amazon S3. The traditional pattern is to create an Event configure in the S3 bucket, which directly triggers an event rather than looking for `PutObject` in CloudTrail. I know that such an event cannot be configured on a suffix. I have not tried capturing an event using your CloudTrail method.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein yes, it is triggering on an API Call via CloudTrail. Is there a way I can attach the S3 event trigger notification directly to the serverless lambda function for an existing bucket? If yes could you please help me with an example to do it through a cloud formation template?

Comment: See: [Amazon S3 Event Notifications - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/NotificationHowTo.html)